# Node app deployed on AWS using Load balancer, ASG and EC2 instances within the private subnets keeps returning 504 error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer

I am deploying a simple Node / Express application on AWS. My Express is basically a very basic app with two routes: `/` for returning a message, "Hello World" and `/health` for load balancer health check.

My Node app is running on port `4000`. I am now trying to deploy my app on AWS. My infrastructure is built using Application Load balancer (within the private subnets), ASG, EC2 instances (within the private subnets) and custom VPC and subnets. But when I access the domain of my internet-facing application load balancer, it keeps returning Gateway Timeout error.

I created a new VPC using the CIDR block, `10.0.0.0/16`.

Then I further split into subnets: 2 public subnets and 2 private subnets as follow.

- `10.0.0.0/18` - public subnet 1 (`NodeApiPublicSubnet1`) in `eu-west-2a`
- `10.0.64.0/18` - public subnet 2 (`NodeApiPublicSubnet2`) in `eu-west-2b`
- `10.0.128.0/18` - private subnet 1 (`NodeApiPrivateSubnet1`) in `eu-west-2a`
- `10.0.192.0/18` - private subnet 2 in (`NodeApiPrivateSubnet2`) `eu-west-2b`

Then I created an Internet Gateway and attached it to my custom VPC.

Then I created 2 NAT Gateways (`NodeApiNatGateway1`), 1 is deployed in public subnet 1 and the other (`NodeApiNatGateway2`) one is deployed in public subnet 2. Elastic IPs are also created for each NAT Gateways.

Then I created 3 route tables (`NodeApiPublicRouteTable`, `NodeApiPrivateRouteTable1` and `NodeApiPrivateRouteTable2`).

This is the route configuration of `NodeApiPublicRouteTable` with the route for the internet gateway:

[image]

This is the subnet associations of `PublicRouteTable`:

[image]

`NodeApiPrivateRouteTable1` is associated to the `NodeApiPrivateSubNet1` and has the routes as follow with a route configuration for `NodeApiNatGateway1`:

[image]

Subnet associations:

[image]

`PrivateRouteTable2` is similar to `PrivateRouteTable1` but instead it is associated to `NodeApiNatGateway2` and `NodeApiPrivateSubnet2`.
[image]

[image]

After I created route tables, I created two security groups (`NodeApiPublicLBSG` and `NodeApiPrivateInstanceSG`), one for internet-facing load balancer and the other one for my instances to be deployed within the private subnets.

Inbound rules for `NodeApiPublicLBSG`:

[image]

Inbound rules of `NodeApiPrivateInstanceSG` (also referencing the `NodeApiPublicLBSG`):

[image]

After I created security groups, I created an EC2 instance (NOTE: I also use this instance later for creating an AMI image). This is how I created the instance. NOTE: I also created an IAM role for instance which has S3 read permission and SSM access permission for connecting to instance vis session manager.

I chose Amazon Linux 2 AMI:

[image]

I also assigned the instance to the right VPC, security group and subnet (`NodeApiPrivateSubnet1`):

[image]

I also attached the IAM role that I mentioned to the instance. Then I launched the instance. Then I connected to the instance via session managers and run the following commands. Basically, it is installing necessary tools/ software, download my project from S3 and run it.

```
sudo -su ec2-user

curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash
source ~/.bashrc

nvm install 16
nvm use 16

npm install -g pm2   

cd ~/
aws s3 cp s3://BUCKET_NAME/app-tier/ app-tier --recursive

cd ~/app-tier
npm install
pm2 start index.js

pm2 list

pm2 startup

pm2 save
```

Everything was fine. The app was up and running on port 4000. I checked running the below command.

```
curl http://localhost:4000/health
```

Then I created an AMI image based off that instance.

After creating the image, I created the target group.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, I set the port to `4000` as my app is running on port 4000. But I did not assign any instances yet as I will do that later.

Then I created an Internet-facing application load balancer as follow.

This is listener which is associated to the target group created in the previous step.

[image]

It's also associated with two public subnets:

[image]

Also associated with two security groups including the default one from VPC:

[image]

After that I created a launch template. I used the AMI image I created. I chose tier 2 micro for instance type. I assigned the `NodeApiPrivateInstanceSG` security group to it. But I did not link the subnets as I will do it with ASG:

[image]

Finally, I created Auto Scaling Group as follows.

I chose the launch template created in the previous step:

[image]

Then I assigned two private subnets:

[image]

I also attached the application load balancer and target group created in the previous steps:

[image]

[image]

After everything has been set up, copied the load balancer's domain in the browser, it kept loading for a while and then I got Gateway timeout error.

I also connected to each of the instances and made sure that application is running on port 4000 using pm2. The app is running. But it is keeps returning gateway timeout error.

What is wrong with my configuration and how can I fix it?

### Additional info

This is the network ACL of my VPC:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have [default network ACLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html#default-network-acl) configured? Also, work through [troubleshoot 504 from ALB](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/504-error-alb).

Comment: I have also updated the question to include the Network ACL details attached to my VPC. Please have a look and let me know if it looks right or wrong. thanks.

Comment: Also I followed this workshop too doing exactly what the instructions say, https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/85cd2bb2-7f79-4e96-bdee-8078e469752a/en-US. But also getting the similar error. But that workshop does not mention about configuring ACLs. Everything looks fine to me.

Comment: It's really annoying that even though I exactly followed the AWS three tier architecture workshop, it does not work. I repeated it like 4 times to ensure that I did not miss anything. Getting the 504 error when the web tier instance is making the API request to the internal load balancer in the private subnets.